# Blank page rendered on deployment (react)

Tags: reactjs, deployment, router, vercel

https://github.com/KaranS09/TemporaryDefiRepo this is a react project i was working on before. It works perfectly on localhost and there are no build errors aswell, but on deploying it to vercel, i get a blank page. I suppose it's because of react-router as this was the first time i used it but i couldn't quite put my finger on it. Any suggestions on how i can fix this?

I tried deploying it on multiple platforms like vercel, netlify and hostinger but faced the same problem everywhere.

Comment: React router is missing in package.json, have you tried `npm i -SE react-router-dom` ?